# Setting FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON of an activity from another activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an activity which calls another activity(not by intent,through an sdk which is not open source). The second activity is a MediaPlayer , since I don't have access to the code of that activity and it is in a jar file, I want to set its FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON activity from some other activity. My intention here is to prevent the screen from turning off during the play of the video in the MediaPlayer.
I'll appreciate if you can help me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, but you can probably do something similar.  When you launch the activity, use startActivityForResult.  At the same time, take a wakelock that keeps the screen on.  When onActivityResult is called, release the wakelock.

Comment: I don't have any problem to keep the screen of the application always on, if there is a way to make the application always on it would even be better. So using wakelock can I achieve that?

Comment: A partial `WakeLock` will not keep the screen on. `SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK`, `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` and `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` are all deprecated.

Comment: To force the application to be on top?  No.  Wakelock is just about keeping the CPU on and the screen lit.  But that's all FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON does anyway.

Comment: @user13 But they all still work.  They're deprecated because Google would prefer you to use other methods, not because they aren't fully functional.

Comment: @GabeSechan  sorry I didn't quite get it. So by using wakelock can I keep the screen of my application always on?

Comment: You can keep the phone screen always on. Keeping your app on screen is impossible, there's no api for that

Comment: @GabeSechan No I don't want to keep my app always on top, I just want to prevent the screen from going off automatically when my video is playing in MediaPlayer

Comment: @GabeSechanThanks Gabe, I tried wakelock with FULL_WAKE_LOCK and it worked.